# Error in creating app service plan in Southeast Asia

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Anyone encountering similar issue? Other region works fine.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJaox.png)

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up because you've hit your subscription's default limit, for this specific region. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-sku-not-available?tabs=azure-cli) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/regional-quota-requests) for more information.

> When considering your vCPU needs across regions, keep in mind the
> following:
>
> 1. Regional vCPU quotas are enforced across all VM series in a given
>    region. As a result, decide how many vCPUs you need in each region in
>    your subscription. If you don't have enough vCPU quota in each region,
>    submit a request to increase the vCPU quota in that region. For
>    example, if you need 30 vCPUs in West Europe and you don't have enough
>    quota, specifically request a quota for 30 vCPUs in West Europe. When
>    you do so, the vCPU quotas in your subscription in other regions
>    aren't increased. Only the vCPU quota limit in West Europe is
>    increased to 30 vCPUs.
> 2. When you request an increase in the vCPU quota for a VM series, Azure
>    increases the regional vCPU quota limit by the same amount.
> 3. When you create a new subscription, the default value for the total
>    number of vCPUs in a region might not be equal to the total default
>    vCPU quota for all individual VM series. This discrepancy can result
>    in a subscription with enough quota for each individual VM series that
>    you want to deploy. However, there might not be enough quota to
>    accommodate the total regional vCPUs for all deployments. In this
>    case, you must submit a request to explicitly increase the quota limit
>    of the regional vCPU quotas.

[This part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/regional-quota-requests#increase-a-regional-vcpu-quota) also show you how to request for increasing the quota - it's generally very straight forward and gets approved automatically within a few mins.

Although the examples above mention VM - the process would generally be the same for different resources with quotas enforced at the subscription level.